# Why am I unable to round the edges of my UIImageView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, calayer

On my Storyboard I have a `UIImageView` in a `UITableViewCell`, and I have an outlet to it in code. In `initWithCoder` (after I imported Quartz) I ask it to round the edges of the image, but it's never done, they're always square.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.postThumbnail.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.postThumbnail.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
        self.postThumbnail.opaque = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

They're for cells, so later on in my table view delegate I set the image. Do I have to round it there as well? Is there no way to universally say "keep it rounded"?

Comment: Show your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have an outlet to `UIImageView` which placed on a cell. Change `cornerRadius` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the method `initWithDecoder:`will be called. If this is the `init` method of your cell class, where the `UIImageView` is connected to, try to use the method `awakeFromNib`.